# Is an "empty" elasticsearch incompatible-snapshots file normal?

Tags: elasticsearch, snapshot

After my first attempt to do a snapshot on my cluster (which took many hours to finish) I found a file `incompatible-snapshots` in the snapshot directory with the contents of `{"incompatible-snapshots":[]}`.  I.e. an empty list ??

Is this normal?  I am guessing it is, but...

Answer (score 1):

I got the issue when i updated elasticsearch version. Elastic use this to store snapshop overdated. Did you upgrade or copypast snapshot manually?

Comment: I got it first time I created a snapshot

Comment: Do you use the same es version on all nodes of the cluster?

Comment: Yes, all nodes are on 6.8.8